# Windows 7 is already installed on my system and then i tried to install ubuntu

Tags: installation

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

Windows 7 is already installed on my system and then i tried to install Ubuntu  12.04 from a USB drive made with LILI program.

Now I am getting black screen or if I use other modes from <kbd>F6</kbd> menu, I get error. How can I install Ubuntu on my system now? please give me a detailed step by step solution.

Comment: check this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to reinstall everything, I would suggest simply formatting the drive and installing ubuntu again. If something went wrong with the installation, this is probably the easiest way.

Burn the ubuntu installation ISO to a CD or DVD and boot from it. If it detects another OS, make sure to select the option to erase it and install ubuntu on the entire disk.

Answer (score 0):

Try ubuntus usb-creator-gtk to create bootable USB Medium. I don't know LILI.

1. run usb-creator-gtk
2. Select .iso to create a bootable usb stick from
3. select usb drive to install to
4. click create
5. finished
   6- reboot from just created usb drive

Comment: This requires the OP has a Ubuntu machine to make the disk with. Unetbootin works well IMO.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of LILI try to use [YUMI](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/downloads/YUMI/YUMI-0.0.7.4.exe) . you can find instructions at

http://www.pendrivelinux.com/yumi-multiboot-usb-creator/

I think it will help you

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Can you provide some detail about your answer?